# Oracle - Apply SQL to all schema in database

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to run the same SELECT against all the schema in my Oracle database.
I found an example of how to do this, but when I try to run it against my database I get the below error:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
```

This is my PLSQL

```
DECLARE
v_sql varchar2(128);
 cursor c1 is
    select username from dba_users WHERE account_status = 'OPEN' and DEFAULT_TABLESPACE not in ('SYSAUX','SYSTEM');
BEGIN
    for REC in c1 loop
        v_sql := 'select * from '||REC||'.accountdetails';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

So this should in effect be doing this...

```
SELECT * FROM USER1.ACCOUNTDETAILS;
SELECT * FROM USER2.ACCOUNTDETAILS;
SELECT * FROM USER3.ACCOUNTDETAILS;
etc.
```

Any advice greatly appreciated

C

From Akina comments, I now have

```
DECLARE
cursor c1 is select username from dba_users WHERE account_status = 'OPEN' and DEFAULT_TABLESPACE not in ('SYSAUX','SYSTEM');
BEGIN
    for REC in c1 loop
        select * from REC.accountdetails;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

but i get

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Comment: *this should in effect be doing this...* Replace you `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` with `SELECT` to ensure that you really obtain those query texts. Assign some of this texts to a variable directly to ensure `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is normally executed.

Comment: I suspect you want `...REC.username || '.accountdetails'`

Comment: Also, you need to store the results of your sql statement into a variable, otherwise it won't run.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? In your cursor loop you're not *doing* anything with the results. As to the error you're getting (`table or view does not exist`), are you sure the user you're running this PL/SQL as has permissions to view this table? Important to note that when running PL/SQL - permissions have to be granted directly, not via a role.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE
v_sql varchar2(4000);
 cursor c1 is
    select o.owner,o.object_name from dba_users u,dba_objects o  WHERE u.account_status = 'OPEN' and u.DEFAULT_TABLESPACE not in ('SYSAUX','SYSTEM')
    and u.username=o.owner and o.object_name='ACCOUNTDETAILS' and o.object_type='TABLE';
BEGIN
    for REC in c1 loop
        v_sql := 'select * from '||REC.owner||'.'||REC.object_name;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this PL/SQL

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT username
    FROM dba_users
    WHERE account_status = 'OPEN'
      AND DEFAULT_TABLESPACE NOT IN ('SYSAUX', 'SYSTEM');
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
    -- Modify the SELECT statement according to your requirements
    SELECT *
    INTO   some_variable
    FROM   accountdetails
    WHERE  username = rec.username;
    -- Do something with the selected data
    
    -- Example: Print the username
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Username: ' || rec.username);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: While possibly correct, a code-only answer helps the person who asked the question, it doesn't do them or future visitors any good.   Please consider improving your answer. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)